# How to add a reset button to a desktop PC?

Tags: hardware-rec

As many modern PCs have no reset button, what would be the best (simplest, cheapest) way to add one (hello to all C64 users)?

Looking for an answer for a typical (minitower) desktop PC.

The first one where I'll be applying the solution would probably be a Medion Akoya P5350 D ([link](http://aldi.medion.com/w6u9mdu38895/mjugrtsl/))

Comment: The answer will be different per type of computer. There is no general solution, you need to narrow your question.

Comment: As someone who builds his own computers.... Huh?  All my desktops came with a reset button as did all motherboards I bought (including recent Z170/skylakes) came with reset pins on the motherboard. Laptops seem to lack them, forciing a power off though, but desktops?

Comment: @Hennes If you deliberately chose cases that have one then yes, but in general must do not have one. For example the one sitting under the desk next to me: [HP EliteDesk](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=c04123137)

Comment: I have not actiuvely selected cases for it, but maybe I am just lucky. Or maybe my sample size was to smal.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reset button is a simple matter, provided your motherboard has pins or other connection for a reset button. Most retail motherboards (Asus, Gigabyte, MSI) have them but many OEM (HP,  Dell, Lenovo, etc) boards do not.

If your does, a simple momentary contact NO (normally open) push button switch connected to the reset button connector on the motherboard will suffice. The switches are available at most electronics component stores (Frye's, MicroCenter) and can be easily mounted by drilling the required size hole in a blank drive bay insert, although mounting in a spot with sufficient space behind it in the front of the case would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your real goal may be to perform a cold system reset (and reboot).  Though a hardwired Reset button is both intuitive and quick, there is a simpler method that doesn't require changing the chassis or adding any switches or extra effort.  You could simply "force" the system to power off, then power it back on again by using the existing power switch.

1. Press and hold the power button for about 10 seconds (in your example, the blue triangle at the bottom of the front bezel), then release. [This will typically force an ATX power supply to power off.]
2. Press the power button again (1~2 seconds) and the system will restart. [Normal power on.]

Or alternatively...

If you truly must have a reset switch, but want to protect it from accidentally being pressed, consider putting a 2mm hole in the front bezel, then mounting a SPST momentary microswitch inside the bezel, and connecting the 2 leads to the reset pins on your m/b.  To reset the system, the user would use a paperclip or similar to press the microswitch lever through the reset hole on the bezel.  This would be the least aesthetically offensive modification, and would prevent accidental system reset.

Comment: Takes more time to find a paperclip here than to hold the power button (or to pull the plug)...

Answer (score 0):

If your motherboard has a pair of RESET pins (look for "front panel connector", "system panel header" or the like in your motherboard's user manual to learn which pins you need), you can use an external button like the following one ([image source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HG7HO22)):

[image: example external button]

Just look for "external power button for PC" on the Internet. These most often come with a reset button and power&HDD LEDs to complete your "virtual front panel".